# Security improvement for hybrid application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, webforms, openid-connect

We are working on an management application that is build using a mix of older and newer technologies and frameworks. The generic architecture looks like:
[Architecture Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGY7Z.png)

It started out as an ASP.NET WebForms app, but when a mobile client was requested, we had to provide the data through an API (WebApi). Now we have .aspx pages running along Angular pages (that call the API). 
We are managing our users in a custom way - they are added by an admin and saved in an SQL DB (there is no registration page) and security is assured by a plain security cookie (encrypted user info) that is set after login and provided with each call (by: .aspx pages, Angular pages, mobile app). 
Now we thought about stepping up our security (authentication and authorization) and user management by using OAuth 2 and Open ID Connect offered by an Identity Provider. Providers like Auth0 or Okta do not offer support for WebForms (documentation is scarce) and we don't know if it's worth implementing OAuth + OIDC by ourselves. 
What would be the right approach for improving security, in the given scenario ?